# Disable apache access log for openshift's app health check

Tags: apache, logging, openshift

I realized Openshift makes health checks in my app each 2/3 seconds, generating a lot of redundant junk in the apache's log. How can i disable log from openshift's health check servers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can perform access logging conditionally, see [Conditional Logs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#conditional). I do not know how Openshift access can be identified, but defining an appropriate [SetEnvIf](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) should be feasible. Then, as mentioned, add the negated environment variable to your logging definition:

```
CustomLog logs/access_log common env=!dontlog
```

Answer (score 0):

A more complete example will be...

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/metrics$" skiplog
CustomLog logs/access.log combined env=!skiplog
```

Where your application exports metrics for Prometheus at the usual `/metrics` endpoint.